# Xamarin forms: Showing DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BINDING_DEBUG_OUTPUT when loading a page

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, unhandled-exception

Redirecting to `App.g.i.cs` when loading a page in xamarin UWP. Code control comes to the following if block.

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

If I mouse over the **e** showing `{Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}`

I am not understanding what is the problem? Is this related to some error in XAML? This issue is only on the windows app, Android and IOS apps parts are working fine.

**XAML page code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Myproject.Pages.CodeValidationPage"
             BackgroundColor="#00aff0">

<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout 
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Orientation="Vertical">

            <Image 
            Source="splash.png"
            HeightRequest="120"
            WidthRequest="120"
            IsVisible="True"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

            <Label
            Text=" Please check your email for the verification code and activate your account. "
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                x:Name="italic_test"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            Margin="3"
            Font="Italic,15"
            TextColor="White"/>

            <Frame
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                CornerRadius="10"
                Margin="20"
                Padding="0">

                <StackLayout 
                    BackgroundColor="White" 
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >

                    <Entry 
                        x:Name="codeentry" 
                        Margin="10,10,10,0"
                        Keyboard="Numeric"
                        Placeholder="Enter Verification Code"/>

                    <Entry 
                        x:Name="passwordentry" 
                        Placeholder="Password" 
                        IsVisible="False"
                        Margin="10,10,10,0"
                        IsPassword="True"/>

                    <Entry 
                        x:Name="confirmpasswordentry" 
                        Margin="10,0,10,-10"
                        IsVisible="False"
                        Placeholder="Confirm Password"
                        IsPassword="True"/>

                    <Button
                        Text="Verify Code" 
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        WidthRequest="150"
                        x:Name="validationButton"
                        TextColor="White"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Font="Bold,15"
                        Margin="5,15,5,10"
                        BorderRadius="20"
                        BackgroundColor="#00aff0" 
                        Clicked="SaveNewPassword"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>

        <Label
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Margin="0,0,0,15"
                x:Name="backto_label"
                TextColor="White"
                Font="Bold,16"
                Text=" Back to Sign Up "/>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: you have an unhandled exception. Set "DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION" in DefineConstants testbox in UWP project settings to not reach this line.

Comment: @magicandre1981  I can't find any defineconstants textbox in UWP project, I have added the screenshot to the question when going to the project properties. Can you please tell on which tab I can find that option?

Comment: under [Build you see the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnz6V.png)

Comment: @magicandre1981 I disable the define DEBUG constant checkbox in the build tab, but no luck. I added a screenshot to the question with the latest observations.

Comment: Hi @SreejithSree, you could check rob's [case reply](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/250e8e87-8eff-4af3-b957-2cf12d7ee89c/can-you-disable-the-disablexamlgeneratedbreakonunhandledexception-flag?forum=winappswithcsharp), in my opinion, you need to check if all the component has been init successfully and the local resource has load correctly. And most problems occur on resource loading.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Edited the question with latest observations, can you please help?

Comment: don't disable debug. looks like you copied/pasted some code you fond somewhere. Use a simple DisplayAlert to show a message with the exception string in unhandled handler.

Comment: I could not figure out  what  is `NathsarTS`  in your screenshot.  It looks like reference project. could you share mini sample?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT "Use a simple DisplayAlert to show a message with the exception string in unhandled handler" - Can you please share this sample code? I didn't get how to write this?

Comment: From your screenshot, `NathsarTS` does not exist, you could check  if `NathsarTS` component exist in your project.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT From the following link I got that code. Can you please go through that and tell what is `NathsarTS?` Is that a Nuget Package? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/250e8e87-8eff-4af3-b957-2cf12d7ee89c/can-you-disable-the-disablexamlgeneratedbreakonunhandledexception-flag?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: @magicandre1981 and NicoZhu-MSFT: For fixing an issue in UWP, I changed the target and min versions of UWP app. Is that changes cause this issue? For more details please go to the following thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706578/reference-to-type-assembly-claims-it-is-defined-in-system-runtime-but-it-co

Comment: I have checked that case. `NathsarTS`  is not nuget package, it is separate common reference library. And you could not  copy/paste code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185339/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Comment: The problem is definitely in XAML, so you should post some code so that we can see what is happening

Comment: @magicandre1981 created a sample, can you please look. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqQr83WMykhefGVlORsBqi1rlNs

Comment: @MartinZikmund I added the XAML code of a page to the question, when I load this page I am getting this error. Can you please look?

Comment: I posted it as answer what I did to get the app running.

Comment: You should not convert to .NET Framework, but to .NET Standard library. That is a different concept. Please look into the documentation to see how to create a .NET Standard library and migrate your code there

Comment: @MartinZikmund So sorry, actually I converted to .Net standared, not to .NET Framework. I used PclToNetStandard.vsix for converting the pcl to .NET Standard as per the answer of  magicandre1981.

Comment: @MartinZikmund I created a new sample for you. Can you please check? Which is a .NET Standard project, converted from PCL.https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqQr83WMykhefgh7vtU0nMCchu0

Comment: @MartinZikmund I have the issue when doing `signup, reset password and join operations`. When doing reset password use `geo@rsvhr.com` as the email. For join enter 5 and search, then click the join button for the test site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is with the `disaplayalert`.

I am using the following code for display alert:

```
await DisplayAlert("Alert", "A verification code has been sent to your email.", "OK");
```

If I changed the above lines like below, no issue will come.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => 
{
    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "A verification code has been sent to your email.", "OK");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With [Xamarin.forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/) [3.x Microsoft moved to .net standard 2.0](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1306).

I was able to compile the code and run the app [after converting your PCL to .net standard 2.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tafuji.pcl2netstandard), updating all nuget packages to last version and changing `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"` to `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"` as [stated in the documentation](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin#when-upgrading-to-30) in your XAML files.

[image]

Clicking on ResetPassword shows a [System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception?view=netstandard-2.0) at this line:

```
string initialLogin = Application.Current.Properties["initialLogin"].ToString();
```

So change it to

```
Application.Current.Properties.TryGetValue("initialLogin", out var initialLogin);
```

to handle the case that "*initialLogin*" was not added to the [Application.Current.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#properties-dictionary) collection. Next check the value for being `!= null` before use it.

Also in `Mainpage.xaml.cs` you do the same mistake with *username* and *password*.

Also change [PDB type from full to pdb-only to allow debugging. This is a known issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48255262/1466046)

So reset works:

[image]

Comment: How many time it take to install? VSIX installer is still running after 1 hour?

Comment: close VS2017 and click on end tasks

Comment: post more details what I should use as test credentials.

Comment: I have the issue on `sign up, password reset and Join operations`. For sign up, you can use any details, enter any `first name, last name and email`. When click the submit button will get that error page. Also when do reset password getting the same error. Please use `geo@rsvhr.com` as the reset password email. You can see a join option in the new sample at the bottom of login page. When click join a new page will come, please enter 5 in the entry and tap search option. Then a community with Join button will show in in the UI. When click the join button will get the same error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and advice, I updated the right answer.